# Where is android studio building my .apk file?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been rebuilding my project from the ground up, so there's been a lot of problems with it. At the moment, everything's working great, except that when I try to run the app, I get the message **'Local path doesn't exist.'**, where the local path is pointing at the path: *AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\MyProject..\build\production\MyProject.apk*, and true enough, there is no .apk file at that location, or indeed anywhere else in the project filesystem.

However, I can build the app with no problems, and running gradlew packageDebug gives me the message '**build successful**', so .apks *should* be being generated. My question is, where are they going, or if they aren't being generated, why not?

Where is the build path of each module set? I'm somewhat confused because the Project Structure->Facets->Android->Compiler settings, Project Structure->Modules->Paths->Compiler Output, build.gradle, and MyProject.iml all seem to have something to do with the build path, but I don't quite understand how they relate

edit: I know where it *should be*, but it's *not there* so I want to know how to change the build path

**edit 2: For some reason running *gradlew build* does create .apks, but not building or running from inside the program**

edit 3: Here's my gradlew build output, note that it does build successfully:

```
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "target" on "com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated@9e9aabc", value: "android-16".
:TwoWayLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:packageReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:TwoWayLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:compileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:prepareRogueProjectTwoWayLibUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:prepareDebugDependencies
:Rogue:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:compileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:validateDebugSigning
:Rogue:packageDebug
:Rogue:assembleDebug
:Rogue:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Rogue:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:compileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:packageRelease
:Rogue:assembleRelease
:Rogue:assemble
:Rogue:check UP-TO-DATE
:Rogue:build
:TwoWayLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:packageDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:TwoWayLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:compileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:check UP-TO-DATE
:TwoWayLib:build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.848 secs
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apk location in New Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620366/apk-location-in-new-android-studio)

Comment: it should be there as explained by Alex or else you can check above answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620366/apk-location-in-new-android-studio/29097183#29097183

Comment: Mine was in ./app/release/app-release.apk

Answer (score 209):

YourApplication\app\build\outputs\apk

Comment: This is the new location.

Comment: Thanks - I found it there for Android Studios 1.1

Comment: in newer version, it is in YourApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\*.apk

Comment: there is a folder named debug inside apk folder and in debug folder is an apk file named app-debug.apk along with a json file

Comment: don't forget to build the apk.

Comment: As of Jan '20: `YourApplication/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`

Comment: is there any way to change it ?

Comment: If you generated an Android App Bundle (AAB): YourApplication\app\release\app-release.aab

Answer (score 32):

You should Build your app instead of debugging process. Just follow this:

```
Build -> Build Bundles/APK(s) -> Build APK(s)
```

[image]

Comment: In case anyone wonders where the file winds up, as I did before I tried this, when the process is complete, there's a small dialog that comes up in the lower right corner of Android studio with a link you can click to open the folder in your file manager application (e.g., File Explorer in Windows).

Answer (score 25):

**After compiling my `code` in Android Studio, I found it here:**

> ~\MyApp_Name\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

Answer (score 24):

Go to AndroidStudio projects File

1. Select the project name,
2. Select app
3. Select build
4. Select Outputs
5. Select Apk

You will find APK files of app here, if you have ran the app in AVD or even hardware device

Comment: Strange,  I am using Android Studio 3.2, in the build directory as you mentioned, there is only `intermediates` directory,  the `Outputs` is missing.

Comment: @AllanRuin did you build the APK?

Comment: please be elaborative with the steps that you have mentioned.

Comment: @ShubhamArya and anyone else, make sure you are in Project view and not Android view in the project navigator then this will make more sense.

Answer (score 19):

For latest Android Studio **Chipmunk|2021.2.1 Patch 2**
the path to the `Apk` file is

```
MySampleAndroidApp\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 11):

I was having the issue finding my debug apk. Android Studio 0.8.6 did not show the apk or even the output folder at project/project/build/. When I checked the same path project/project/build/ from windows folder explorer, I found the "output" folder there and the debug apk inside it.

Comment: Explorer crashes pretty hard if you have this location open and 'clean project' =)

Comment: Can't believe I wasted so much time just because I forgot that just  because Android Studio doesn't always show you all the directories...

Answer (score 10):

in android 3.1.0 Above use below path to find signed version of APK

```
home/AndroidStudioProjects/<projedct name>/app/app-release.apk
```

and in windows

```
AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\release\app-release.apk
```

Answer (score 9):

For Android Studio:

If you haven't built the APK at least once, you might not find the /Outputs/APK folder. Go to Build in Android Studio and one of the last three options is Build APK, select that. It will then create that folder and you will find your APK file there.

Comment: All the above didn't work for me and this one does. After `Build APK` it will also pop up a dialog telling you to `locate` your apk, how convenient!

Answer (score 8):

You can find it in the

```
project -> app (or your main app module) -> build -> outputs -> apk
```

Comment: This is the up-to-date one that actually works for me especially if you are looking for the release version. I am on Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Canary 9.

Answer (score 7):

**Mine application's apk was at this location**

***C:\Users\haseeb_mir\AndroidStudioProjects\MyTestApp\app\build\outputs\apk\debug***

Answer (score 6):

When Gradle builds your project, it puts all APKs in build/apk directory. You could also just do a simple recursive find command for *.apk in the top level directory of your project.

Here is a better description...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwjEZ.png]

View full image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwjEZ.png

Comment: Where is that directory defined? Because I can't find any apk files anywhere in my project filestsyem

Comment: Like in my edit - I know where it *should be*, but it's not there, so maybe the output path is broken somehow?

Comment: I've added it. The only dodgy thing is that my library TwoWayLib seems to be building twice. That doesn't explain why android studio can't build apks though

Comment: I also have the same problem - neither Gradle nor Android Studio actually create an apk file.

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 Patch 3

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, built on March 16, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64

***yourProject**/build/intermediates/apk/debug/debug.apk*

Answer (score 2):

In my case to get my debug build  -  I have to turn off Instant Run option :

File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Then after run project  - I found my build into Application\app\build\outputs\appDebug\apk directory

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132770/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist/17330314#17330314).

TL;DR: clean, then build.

```
./gradlew clean packageDebug
```

Comment: Similar problem, but in my case running that command does cause it to build once, but it still doesn't work from inside android studio.

Comment: It still doesn't create the .apk file?

Answer (score 1):

When you have android studio make your signed apk file it uses

```
    <property name="ExportedApkPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/PROJNAME/APPNAME.apk" />
```

inside workspace.xml to find out where to place it. However, if you use `./gradlew assembleRelease` it places it inside PROJNAME/build/apk. I have the same problem. For some reason my android studio will not show me anything inside the apk subdirectory so the apk is for all intents and purposes missing. But if you search with finder it's most definitely there.

Comment: path: /.idea/workspace.xml property: <property name="ExportApk.ApkPath" value="..." />

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small gradle script, which should help to find the output apk file. Probably it will work with aab:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.getAssembleProvider().get().doLast { assemble ->
        def outputFile = variant.outputs*.outputFile
        println "\n\n\nOUTPUT FILE -> $outputFile\n\n\n"
    }
}
```

Put it insid the `android` body.
Have a good coding

Answer (score 1):

As of Nov 2023, for react native, it is located in: /android/app/build/outputs/apk/development/debug/here-is-the-apk

Answer (score 1):

With "Android Studio 2023.2.1", now in 2024-04, it is like this:

5.1 ( Burger Menu ) > Build > Rebuild Project

```
”( Burger Menu ) > Build > Select Build Variant…”.
    “Build Variants:”.
        “Module” = ”:app”
        “Active Build Variant”.
            “debug ( default )”.
            “release”.
”( Burger Menu ) > Build > Rebuild Project”.
    “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk”.
    “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk”.
You may either create a “debug” or a “release” item.
One directory with the item is created. Other items in the directory are deleted.
If the other directory exist, it is deleted.
    When building a “release” build, the “debug” directory is deleted.
    When building a “debug” build, the “release” directory is deleted.
So you can't generate “bundle” files by this.
So you may have just either a “debug” or a “release” item at the same time :-).
```

5.2 ( Burger Menu ) > Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s)

```
”( Burger Menu ) > Build > Select Build Variant…”.
    “Build Variants:”.
        “Module” = ”:app”
        “Active Build Variant”.
            “debug ( default )”.
            “release”.
”( Burger Menu ) > Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s)”.
    “Build APK(s)”:
        “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk”.
        “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk”.
    “Build Bundle(s)”.
        “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\build\outputs\bundle\debug\app-debug.aab”.
        “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\build\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab”.
    You may either create a “debug” or a “release” item.
    One directory with the item is created. Other items in the directory are deleted.
    If the other directory exist, it is not deleted.
    So you may have “apk” and “bundle” directories and so “apk” and “bundle” files at the same time :-).
```

5.3 ( Burger Menu ) > Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK...

```
”( Burger Menu ) > Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK…”.
    “Build APK(s)”.
        “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\debug\app-debug.apk”.
        “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\release\app-release.apk”.
    “Build Bundle(s)”
        “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\debug\app-debug.aab”.
        “AndroidStudioProjects\{project name}\app\release\app-release.aab”.
    You may either create “debug” or “release” items, or “debug” and “release” items at the same time.
    One directory with the item is created. Other items in the directory are deleted.
    If one item is generated, and if the other directories exist, they are not deleted.
    So you may have “debug” and “release” directories directories at the same time :-). But you can have either “apk” and “bundle” files at the same time :-(.
```