# Gradle script rename file problems

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I use the code below to generate an .apk file and it works fine.
But, to be able to debug I need to comment the code around "applicationVariants.all", otherwiser Android Studio says the file was not found.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def apk = output.outputFile;
                    def newName = "app-release-" + getDate() + ".apk";
                    output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

How can I do to make it work for generate .apk file and also to debug on Android Studio?

**UPDATE**

I found what is happening, actually as I use date and time in the file name, the time in the generated file is different from the time that Android Studio tries to install.

My function getDate() returns this:

```
def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmm')
    return formattedDate
}
```

The file created is app-release-201507110957.apk.
However, in the Android Studio console, the error is:

```
Uploading file
    local path: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/AndroidstudioProjects/App/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-201507110956.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.domain.app
Local path doesn't exist.
```

The file name on generated file has 1 minute ahead than the file name Android Studio tries to install.
Any idea about how I can fix that? I would like to have hour and minute in the file name because I might generate more than one version a day for QA team.

Comment: `applicationVariants` is not a meber of `buildTypes.release` ... it is a sibling to `buildTypes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by verifying if the variant is debuggable or not.

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                if (!variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
                    variant.outputs.each { output ->
                        def apk = output.outputFile;
                        def newName = "app-release-" + getDate() + ".apk";
                        output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Like that I apply my file name only for release version. Debuggable ones will continue with same name set by Android Studio, so it won't generate problems when debugging the app.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the renaming is part of your release build. Just put the renaming as general action, like this:

```
android {

  ...

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      variant.outputs.each { output ->
      def apk = output.outputFile;
      def newName = "app-release-" + getDate() + ".apk";
      output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still same problem: "Uploading file
 local path: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/AndroidstudioProjects/App/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-201507091037.apk
 remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.domain.myapp
Local path doesn't exist."

Comment: did you try to add a debug build type as you did for the release type (see my updated answer).

Comment: I found what is happening. Please see my updated question.

Comment: did you take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132770/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist