# Getting an error while trying to execute application which has been imported from Eclipse into Android Studio?

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-studio

I am getting the error while I try to run my application in both device and emulator,I have added the issue shown in Android studio.I tried restarting IDE & other basic stuff as we generally do,nothing seems to be working..Kindly guide me to sort out this issue.Thank you.

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: emulator-5554 (AVD_for_3_2in_HVGA_slider_ADP1)
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/myMac/workspace/TestFolder/MyApp/build/apk/MyApp-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.is.MyApp
Local path doesn't exist.
```

Comment: Does the local path exist? Is the file MyApp-debug-unaligned.apk in /Users/myMac/workspace/TestFolder/MyApp/build/apk/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994596/android-studio-not-loading-on-device-local-path-doesnt-exist/17330227#17330227)?

Basically, from commandline, navigate to the root directory of your project and run

```
./gradlew clean packageDebug
```