# Android Gradle 1.8 Download Error

Tags: android, gradle

First My old Android Studio project is give "android Local path doesn't exist." error.
After this question help me but my project not fixed. [Android Studio - local path doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist)

I'm following in this order.

1- Change gradle-wrapper.properties like this

```
    #Sun Oct 06 12:17:11 EEST 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip
```

2- build.gradle like this;

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
```

3- File->Synchronize
4- File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
5- Run project.

But When Run project I get this error

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip'.: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip'.
```

My project not working.

Please Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solutions: (for v.0.3.0 and maybe above)

- Delete your '.gradle' folder in your user folder. On next start Android Studio will redownload it (Android Studio uses its own gradle wrapper)
- Try downloading [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) yourself and tell Android studio to use that. (Settings -> Gradle)
- Try `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3+'` in your gradle file