# Why am I getting "Local path does not exist" from my Android project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am getting the following notification in IntelliJ IDEA when I try to run my 
Android project:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: emulator-5554 (jkj)
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\REACH9\androidapi\muzima-android\target\muzima-android.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.muzima
Local path doesn't exist.
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here all the possible solutions:

Solution 1: Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist) and read the accepted answer

Solution 2:
Open the `.iml` file with your **editor**. Under `<configuration>`(where you have all those `<option name=...>` paths, add this under all those paths:

```
<option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/muzima-android-debug-unaligned.apk" />
```

Solution 3:
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Your Project -> Dependencies -> Uncheck the project (only depend on the aar)

Comment: my apk is not even generated

Comment: You don't have IML files?

Comment: i have one iml file for the module

Comment: Edit that according to the instructions at the bottom of the page

Comment: I have this:  <option name="APK_PATH" value="/target/muzima-android.apk" />

Comment: what should i change the APK_PATH to?

Comment: Hmm, what is the name of the iml file you just gave? Is it something like your_project_name.iml?

Comment: Waiting for device.
Target device: emulator-5554 (jkj)
Uploading file
 local path: C:\Users\REACH9\androidapi\muzima-android\build\apk\muzima-android-debug-unaligned.apk
 remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.muzima
Local path doesn't exist.

Comment: Edited answer again. If it's not working, then I'm fresh out of ideas. Solution 2 worked for me. Solution 1 might work for you.

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me. Worth noting the exact location that this line needs to be added, since you might have multiple <configuration> blocks: it is under <module [...]> / <component name="FacetManager"> / <facet type="android" name="Android"> / <configuration> (on IntelliJ 14.0.2)