# How to reset to default configuration in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I totally messed up my Android Studio and I don't know how to revert it back. When ever I create new project this is what I get.

[image]

Please point me to the right way on how to make it work again..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio

Comment: does not solve my issue... .AndroidStudioPreview does not exist in my directory...

Comment: it's look like gradle issue or android SDK doesn't parse. open the android studio and go to settings > project template > SDK and choose the right SDK setting their on the front-window. Secondly delete the gradle and make a project so it will download the latest gradle and will fix for you. on your project you need to use that version if you are using older gradle before.

Comment: Try my answer at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086042/how-to-get-gradle-1-9-in-android-studio-0-3-6-running/20095480#comment30677049_20095480

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't mash up! Simple, but I only know for windows

Go to this location in your pc C:\Users[Username]

In this location you have noticed a direcctory call .AndroidStudio

Delete it.

Now your android studio is totally reset.

### To Get the Preview

You have to set the path of your sdk.

right click on the project folder (app) --> Open Module Settings --> SDK Location on sidebar --> setup your sdk folder

Good Luck

Answer (score 23):

in mac

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
```

Answer (score 4):

Сreate a file: gradle.xml into your .idea project directory. The file should have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="gradleHome" value="YOUR_GRADLE_HOME_DIRECTORY" />
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/YOUR_PROJECT_MODULE_DIR" />
          </set>
        </option>
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

Save project and relaunch Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

File -> Export Settings [find explorer settings.jar] 
delete file [settings.jar]

Answer (score 1):

DELETE FILE : .AndroidStudio3.6

Windows 
Go to this location in your pc C:\Users[Username]
In this location you have noticed a direcctory call .AndroidStudio

MAC
GoTo 
 /System/Library/Caches OR /System/Library/AndroidStudio3.6

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, go to Build, then clean project, worked for me when my project turned in a mess and couldn't build

Answer (score 0):

Look for folder .AndroidStudioX.X (X.X is software version) at location C:\Users\UserName. Delete that folder and your Android Studio will reset.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reset it you must to delete this file C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME.AndroidStudio2.2

AndroidStudio2.2 decide about your android studio version for me it is 2.2 delete it and it will work that is it :)

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 33

```
$ rm -rf /home/USERNAME/.config/Google/AndroidStudio{YYYY.#}

$rm -rf /home/messi/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3
```