# White Line keeps blocking codes in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

It's been a while and I'm new to Android Studio, this very white line or whatsoever keeps blocking my view over codes deceasing visibility and compels me to keep rebuilding my project and yet nothing happens.

[image: A white color line covering my code]

Please suggest me a way or a reason which can help me out.

Comment: is that your cursor? cause i can't see the cursor anywhere in editor

Comment: I took a screenshot and yes, it's my cursor which got lost in that white horizontal line once i clicked it.k

Comment: Check the values in Files > Settings > Editor >General > Appearance and uncheck the block caret if it is checked. Let me know

Comment: I have same problem. Tried @Sam suggestion but "Use block caret" is unchecked. Restarting AS solve problem but this is not a solution. Anybody experiencing this unusual problem? Keep showing in AS 3.1.1

Comment: I went through all these steps and many others but wasn't able to achieve a positive outcome

Comment: @Xavier Prince At the end of the white line, hold a long left click (for 3-4 sec) and then click on the other line of code. White line should disappear. Try that. :)

Comment: what happens if you reset Android Studio to default settings as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582577/how-to-reset-to-default-configuration-in-android-studio/31228003)?