# Android Studio Editor foreground color

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with the Android studio Editor, Whenever I am typing, there is a white foreground covering the text. How can I change this?

[image]

Comment: at the beginning the first thought was that you have the "INS" key enabled but maybe you can reset your Android Studio like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582577/how-to-reset-to-default-configuration-in-android-studio/31228003)? NOTE: you can even back up instead of deleting, just in case

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu “File > Settings> Editor > Color&Fonts > General”
Find “Identifier under caret” and change Foreground or/and Background colors with a color you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your settings from Color Scheme:

Go to `Settings -> Color Scheme -> General -> Restore Defaults.. -> Apply`

[image: color scheme]