# Local Path doesn't exist Android Studio 1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I recently downloaded the newest Android Studio 1.0 release and immediately began going through hell to try to get a new project up and running. I created a new Maps Project and as soon as I go to run, it gives me the following:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: motorola-xt1063-ZX1D3226RL
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\WebProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\BlocWork\BlocSpot\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.richluick.blocspot
Local path doesn't exist.
```

Now, I realize that there are similar questions out there, but nothing I try is working. I updated the .iml file like most people have suggested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="java-gradle" name="Java-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="BUILD_FOLDER_PATH" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    <option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/blocspot-debug-unaligned.apk" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/main" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/test" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

That isnt working for me. As others also sugested I tried the `gradlew clean  packagedebug --debug` command and got the following:

```
14:34:14.187 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:34:14.190 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:34:14.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:34:14.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:34:14.202 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
14:34:14.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:34:14.207 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:34:14.210 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have no understanding as to why or how a Null Pointer Exception is being thrown when compiling he gradle. I have been working on this for hours and I just cannot get this to work. I hope somebody can help me with this. The stacktrace from the error is below.

```
14:34:14.212 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.createItemNode(PreDexCache.java:189)
14:34:14.214 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.createItemNode(PreDexCache.java:60)
14:34:14.216 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache.saveItems(PreProcessCache.java:486)
14:34:14.218 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache.clear(PreProcessCache.java:375)
14:34:14.220 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache$clear$0.call(Unknown Source)
14:34:14.222 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
14:34:14.224 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
14:34:14.226 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
14:34:14.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_configureProject_closure1.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:318)
14:34:14.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:34:14.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:34:14.234 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:34:14.236 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
14:34:14.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
14:34:14.239 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)    
14:34:14.241 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
14:34:14.243 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
14:34:14.245 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
14:34:14.246 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
14:34:14.248 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
14:34:14.250 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
14:34:14.251 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
14:34:14.254 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
14:34:14.257 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
14:34:14.259 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:111)
14:34:14.262 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
14:34:14.264 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
14:34:14.268 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
14:34:14.270 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
14:34:14.272 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
14:34:14.276 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
14:34:14.281 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
14:34:14.284 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
14:34:14.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
14:34:14.289 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
14:34:14.291 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
14:34:14.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
14:34:14.346 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
14:34:14.348 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
14:34:14.351 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
14:34:14.353 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
14:34:14.356 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
14:34:14.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
14:34:14.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:34:14.581 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:34:14.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:34:14.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
14:34:14.633 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
14:34:14.636 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
14:34:14.649 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
14:34:14.651 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:34:14.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:34:14.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:34:14.657 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
14:34:14.659 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
14:34:14.661 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
14:34:14.664 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
14:34:14.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Comment: I have the same exact issue.

Comment: @Maher4Ever Maybe its a bug with the new Android Studio. Did you update to Studio 1.0?

Comment: It seems like it. In the previous Beta version this problem didn't exist. I just updated Android Studio to 1.0 and now I can't even run a new empty project.

Comment: Yeah same. Hopefully somebody has figured this out. had no problem with the previous versions

Comment: Do [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19496969/2911458) help at all?

Comment: @stkent it doesnt appear that gradle-wrapper exists in the most recent update, so I do not think that is viable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this. It helped me, FINALLY !!!

1. close android studio
2. Download http://goo.gl/v0UPm6
3. goto \sdk
4. rename 'tools' to 'tools1' (In case you need backup)
5. extract this zip to \sdk
6. it will make tools folder in \sdk
7. restart studio and errors will be gone

Source: [Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/107852486976928213243/posts/eASLDXpavAX)

PD: Thank you, Aman ;) PD2: Android SDK Tools 24.0.1 is coming !!!

Comment: Well sir, that seems to have done the trick! Looks like the issue is with the sdk. I'll keep an eye out for 24.0.1

Comment: still error existing for gradle 1.2.3 and android studio 1.3.please help me

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved it:

In application's `build.gradle` file make sure gradle version is atleast `1.1.0` like this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
```

and the `repositories` section contains `mavenCentral()` instead of `jCentral()`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- [Check for known issues which occurred during the upgrade to 1.0](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)
- [Verify that your Gradle project files have been properly upgraded](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0)

If all else fails, revert to [v.0.9.3 found on the Canary](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-9-3) channel. Hopefully Google sorts out the issue sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thanks Stan. I was actually having the same issues when I created a new project from scratch in the new version. In that case, it didn't look like any of that was the issue. For now I'm going to revert to 0.9.3 so I can move forward

Comment: still error existing for gradle 1.2.3 and android studio 1.3.please help me