# Android Studio - Error: Local path doesn't exists - No apk generated

Tags: android

I recently downloaded latest version of Android Studio today. I configured and setup everything properly but when i create a new project and try to run and debug in the connected phone, it will show this error.

> Error: Local path doesn't exists.

Also, i search for apk file but no apk was generated anywhere.

I am using Android Studio 1.0 built on December 5 2014.
SDK manager is also no starting from Android studio.

Please help.

Comment: After ensuring that you have the SDK installed correctly which I assume that you have done. I would also like you to build the project, don't just run the configuration. This is not an answer, I am just trying to get more information on the problem.

Comment: Did you upgraded your tools to version 24 or updated any component of your studio?

Comment: I just downloaded the latest Android Studio 1.0 and it install everything itself. I think it have Tools v24.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem since update to 1.0 version, the bug comes from an internal script which is supposed to finds the distribution of Java but isn't working correctly on 32-bit Windows systems (SDK Manager was also impossible to run) and it has been fixed in the 24.0.1 release of the SDK.

Solution :

In line 27 of tools/lib/find_java.bat has a problem:

```
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
```

You must remove space after "arch_ext=32". Correct code is:

```
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32|| set arch_ext=64
```

You should be able to open SDK Manager by now, and update Android SDK Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Read this possible duplicate

[Android Studio - local path doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist)

As for the APK, it does not get generated unless you do it.

It is meant for release your project into android file format when you are ready to distribute it.

I took a screenshot for you to see:

[image]

Comment: I am not building to distribute, i m just running in my connected device via adb. but getting that error.

Comment: I read all posts in that link but i cannot change gradle version below 1.0 as it shows error if i do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using studio on Windows and your windows username contains special symbols like '&' - RENAME YOUR USERNAME (and user folder)!

Answer (score 0):

My Issue has been resolved by following answer here https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2pfm2e/android_studio_local_path_doesnt_exist/ .

**Please find the main points as follows.**

Assuming you are on a mac/linux machine. If on Windows, use "gradlew.bat" instead of "./gradlew":

1) Close Android Studio

2) Open command line to the root of your project (the location of gradlew)

3) Run "./gradlew clean" to clean your project

4) Run "./gradlew --stop" to kill off any remnant Android Studio gradle daemons which may be caching stuff

5) Run "./gradlew assembleDebug" to build your project anew. (I am assuming you are building a basic debug configuration. If not, feel free to run "assemble" with your custom configuration.) If there are any issues with the project, you will see them here.

6) Restart Android Studio and try building again.