# Android Studio - Debug On Device

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, media

I am using Android Studio to make my app.  I've successfully connected my device to my PC and enabled USB debugging in Settings -> Applications -> Development -> Enable USB Debugging.

When I press run in Android Studio, my device shows up on the running devices list, but when I click run I get this error:

> Waiting for device.
>        Target device: sony_ericsson-r800x-43423541314438303654
>        Uploading file
>        local path:
>        C:\Users\DylanPhillips\AndroidStudioProjects\MediaRecorder\Application\build\outputs\apk\Application-debug.apk
>        remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.mediarecorder
>        Local path doesn't exist.

How do I fix this error, so the app will run on my phone for me to test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio - local path doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist)

Comment: What happens when you use the ADB from the command line. If you haven't used it before it is really good http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tryed to do Build->Rebuild Project and Build->Clean Project