# Android Studio - Local path doesn't exist. (debug using an Android phone)

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, adb, android-debug

I have been trying to use my phone to debug, and keep getting the error "Local path doesn't exist."

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: htc-htc_one_mini_2-SH45LWR05741
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\game\MyGame\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.xxx.MyGame
Local path doesn't exist.
```

I have seen other posts on this error where people tell you to write this in the app.iml file:

```
<option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/(apk file name that was found earlier with apk extension)" />
```

but there is no .apk file in the game directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist

Comment: I believe this should be fixed if you update your SDK to 24.0.1.