# Android Studio 1.0.2 Error - "Local path doesn't exist"

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently starting using Android Studio again and for some reason my app won't run on my mobile device.

I keep getting this error:

> Waiting for device.
>
> Target device: oneplus-a0001-d9e029e0
>
> Uploading file
>   local path:
>   C:\Users\FV\Desktop\ \Project1\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>   remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.fv4.project.one
>
> Local path doesn't exist.

I've synced the project with Gradle files and I have tried every solution in this popular [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist) as well as solutions mentioned in some other posts. Nothing seems to work.

**EDIT:** Also, I watched this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4WcMIyc8OQ&feature=youtu.be) and there actually is no .apk file in the directory that the person pointed to. Maybe that's what the issue is? How do I fix that, if it is in fact the issue?

What else could I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Try doing clean and then build. It is possible that you have errors and AS is unable to build your app.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I am still getting the same error. Also, I've just edited my question with another piece of information that may be useful

Comment: Sorry, I don't have other ideas, besides this one and other solutions you have already mentioned. BTW, there is newer version of AS 1.1, maybe upgrading can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see android studio searching for the path you mentioned:

> local path: C:\Users\FV\Desktop\ \Project1\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

I noticed there's a block in the path that states:

> Desktop\ \Project1

Unless that's a typo, I think that's why Android Studio fails to find the path, Android Studio warns you against using paths with spaces or special characters in them while creating your project, because it might fail to find the path, and that might cause problems like the one you are experiencing.

Please try to move your project directory to a more conventional path (C:\Project1 is the safest bet, but others can be used aswell) and see if you are still having this issue

Comment: I just moved it to a different directory, without spaces or special characters. Still having the same issue. I also did a reinstall of Android Studio. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It probably won`t matter much, but are you running Android Studio as an administrator? If not, please do and try again

Comment: I was running AS as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I rebooted the system and switched off antivirus and it helped :)