# android gradle Local path doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-studio, build, gradle

When i run my app every time, versionName is incremented in Manifest file.
*20389* means that is old version name, 20390 is incremented number.

[image]

Project is built successfully like *BUILD SUCCESSFUL*. But the question is that why Android studio caches previous apk version. Here is what is error:

> Target device: lge-nexus_5-061642fd00511249
>   Uploading file
>       local path: H:\customFolder\app\build\outputs\apk\MyAppName-0.6.200_20383-debug.apk
>       remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.app
>   Local path doesn't exist.

As you pay attention when app runs on a device, android studio try to instal *20383* version of apk. It is wrong. Could anyone help me? I've googeled and saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist).

Here is how i can change manifest file with gradle script:

```
def updateRevisionNumber () {//autoIncrement Version Name
  def currentVersion = getVersionName();
  def currentRevisionInManifest =           currentVersion.substring(currentVersion.indexOf("_")+1);
  def lastRevision = Integer.parseInt(currentRevisionInManifest) + 1;
  println("currentRevisionInManifest: " + currentRevisionInManifest);
  println("lastRevision: " + lastRevision);

  def oldText = manifestFile.getText();
  def changedText =      oldText.replace(currentRevisionInManifest,lastRevision+"");
  manifestFile.setText(changedText);}
```

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of editing your manifest file during the build, you can override the version name in the android section of your manifest :

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        versionName someScriptToComputeVersionName()
        ...
```

And there is at least 2 good reasons to do it that way :

- the build process won't change your source code (i.e. AndroidManifest.xml will not be modified - at least the AndroidManifest.xml in your *editable* sources won't be modified)
- there are good chances that Android Studio will be happy.

Now your problem is to define correctly the function `someScriptToComputeVersionName()` , that's up to you.

IMO, simply incrementing a number is probably not the best choice and you should probably go for a solution were you build the version name based on VCS revision number.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml is changing without doubt. Here is _android:versionName="0.6.200_20390"_

Comment: I didn't say that your AndroidManifest.xml didn't change... but look into <PROJECT_DIR>\build\intermediates\manifests\... you will see that Android Studio is using another AndroidManifest.xml to build the apk (the result of a merge in a multi-module project, or the result of injection of some configuration from your build.gradle). I don't know when `updateRevisionNumber()` is executed, but I guess that it is too late (i.e. AndroidStudio don't see the change)

Comment: All of them is changed, but a bit strange matter to me is that apk is being installed when i run _installDebug_ via Gradle Tasks.