# When running the "Cordova build android" I'm getting the below exception

Tags: android, cordova

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
  >   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
  >   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
  >   repo1.maven.org
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Java SSL connection error, you need to add the appropriate SSL certificate to the Java keystore for Java accept the connection.

> ### Step 1 : Download the certificate
>
> **With Mozilla Firefox:**
>
> 1. Go to https://repo1.maven.org
> 2. Click on the green padlock at the left of adress bar.
> 3. Click on Details.
> 4. Click on View certificate.
> 5. Click on Details.
> 6. Click on Export.
> 7. Export file to "X.509 Certificate (PEM) (*.crt; *.pem)"
>
> ### Step 2 : Add the certificate to default java keystore
>
> ```
> sudo keytool -import -alias MavenRepo -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /PATH/TO/YOUR/EXPORTED/FILE.crt
> ```
>
> Your `$JAVA_HOME` variable is normally declared in your `.bashrc` file, so you can use this command just replacing the `/PATH/TO/YOUR/EXPORTED/FILE` parameter.
>
> PS : The default password of java keystore is : changeit
>
> <sub>From: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6362#issuecomment-189852511</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I got in same trouble, previously I was using cordova 4.0 and eclipse which was using ant for build.

But from cordova 5.0 it requires gradle. I just installed android studio and mapped my old sdk downloaded with eclipse. As I mapped it and opened one of cordova created project in android studio.
I got one error but due to [one of stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist), I solved the issue.

Created new project and it took some time to download all the dependencies, but at last it solved. Now I can create with CMD.

**So key of the answer is you need to install android studio if you are still using eclipse.**

check mine answer here as well [getting gradle error while creating cordova project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995348/getting-gradle-error-while-creating-cordova-project)