# getting gradle error while creating cordova project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, gradle

I just updated cordova version from 4.0 to 5.1, and everything worked fine also in creating project. But as soon as I gave command of **cordova build** I got below error.

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/co
m/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/bu
ild/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated
```

After 2 days suffering I came to know it's coming due to gradle, I downloaded and added it also in environment variable. I do get this error also when I go to android folder in cordova project and give command of **gradle init**. Don't know what can be reason of it. Am still using eclipse instead of android studio can it also be a reason ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK silly answer, previously I was using cordova 4.0 and eclipse which was using ant for build.

But from cordova 5.0 it requires gradle. I just installed android studio and mapped my old sdk downloaded with eclipse. As I mapped it and opened one of cordova created project in android studio.
I got one error but due to [one of stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist), I solved the issue.

Created new project and it took some time to download all the dependencies, but at last it solved. Now I can create with CMD.

**So key of the answer is you need to install android studio if you are still using eclipse.**

Answer (score 3):

This is a Java SSL connection error, you need to add the appropriated SSL certificate to the Java Keystore for Java accept the connection.

> ### Step 1: Download the certificate
>
> **With Mozilla Firefox:**
>
> 1. Go to https:// repo1.maven.org (remove the space).
> 2. Click on the green padlock at the left of the address bar.
> 3. Click on Details.
> 4. Click on View certificate.
> 5. Click on Details.
> 6. Click on Export.
> 7. Export file to "X.509 Certificate (PEM) (*.crt; *.pem)"
>
> ### Step 2: Add the certificate to default Java Keystore
>
> ```
> sudo keytool -import -alias MavenRepo -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /PATH/TO/YOUR/EXPORTED/FILE.crt
> ```
>
> Your `$JAVA_HOME` variable should be declared in your [.bashrc file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables), so you can use this command just replacing the `/PATH/TO/YOUR/EXPORTED/FILE` parameter.
>
> PS: The default password of Java Keystore is: `changeit`
>
> <sub>From: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6362#issuecomment-189852511</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Problem is due to Proxy 
When you are in corporate network It may be happened. Don't Worry
 gradle.properties which consist of proxy setting ie

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Add gradle.properties file your platform/android

& then Build. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but it was after i installed git which in turn changed my environment variables. I went back there to remove the added path and it worked

Answer (score 0):

if you are behind a proxy, try "npm config " command. I met similar issue and solved by setting the proxy with:

```
"npm config set proxy http://mydomain:proxyPort"
"npm config set proxy https://mydomain:proxyPort"
```