# Build errors in corodva, ionic project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

### The project gets build successfully if we select Ripple - IOS, however for Android - Device the build shows following errors:

MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
  * What went wrong:
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
>   MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Required by:
>          Required by:
>   MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  :android:unspecified
>              :android:unspecified
>   MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
>   MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused
>   Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 44.203 secs
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
  * Try:
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Will you run into see issue when building a blank new Cordova project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be seeing this error if your developer PC is behind a network proxy. If that's the case, then make sure you're first working with at least [Update 8 of the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/04/visual-studio-taco-update-8-and-new-ionic-templates/), which improve support for network proxies.

Also, from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178564/406100) I found, you may try customizing your proxy settings for Gradle. The answer from the referenced post mentions creating a `gradle.properties` file, using the following code as a guide for your specific proxy settings:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

(Learn more about these settings in the [official Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy))

Since you're using Visual Studio, your best practice here is to actually place the `gradle.properties` file in the `res\native\android` folder of your project. Upon build, that file will then be copied into the `platforms\android` folder used by Cordova.

Comment: Glad to see this helped! Did Update 8 of the tools fix your issue, or the Gradle.properties file?

Comment: creating the `gradle.properties` file with `http` instead of `https` worked for me