# Ionic build android throws `Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0` on Ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

This is my stacktrace after `ionic build android`, after the simple three steps to begin working with `ionic`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

All the code is the default code coming with `$ ionic start myApp tabs`

I tried to change gradle version, update cordova.
I've also tried to add this lines in build.gradle:

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
```

I also did that, just in case:
[When running the "Cordova build android" I'm getting the below exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078110/when-running-the-cordova-build-android-im-getting-the-below-exception)

Answer (score 1):

It's now 2023 and I was still getting this error when running a project via the Ionic VS Code plug in. The problem is that I have Gradle 8.0.2 installed yet the plug is expecting Gradle 8.0.0 and keeps updating the project build file accordingly.

The solution:

- Update the Gradle class path dependency in /android/build.gradle to the installed version.
- Run the project from the command line using: `ionic capacitor run android --external`

To enable live reload, add the --livereload or -l parameter to the ionic command.

To make life easy, I've added 'android' and 'android:live' scripts to my package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolve it installing manually gradle.

https://gradle.org/gradle-download/

I made these commands:

```
curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash

sdk install gradle 2.1 # Changing 3.1 version to 2.1
```

I had to restart my computer to get the paths configured correctly.
Previously I checked that it was configured correctly java and his paths but I don't think it has been important to solve it.