# android studio upgrade to 1.2.1.1 results in "local path doesnt exist" error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

ive recently upgraded to android studio 1.2.1.1 and all of a sudden when I run my project iam getting the error "local path doesnt exist"?

this is due to the fact that the debug .apk file is not in the location the IDE is looking.

local path: C:\Users\eoin_a\AndroidStudioProjects\XmppTest\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

ive searched myself and the apk isn't there. In fact i cant seem to find the .apk file in my project at all?

Ive tried a number of solutions Ive seen on previously asked questions but Iam getting no joy here. Ive tried syncing with gradle and clean the project with no luck.

Ive tried in cmd "gradlew clean packageDebug" to no avail.

i would try adding this to the project .iml file

```
<option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/apk file name" />
```

inside    tags.

but I dont have a .apk file or I cant find it. 
If anyone could help me out here that would be awesome!

also withing my dependencies in gradle I have gradle plugin version 1.2.3

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

EDIT:

just thought id put up my gradle.build files as they may be of use. Iam still not sure whats going on

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.eoin_a.xmpptest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'


compile ("org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1")
        {
            exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
            exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        }
compile ("org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1")
        {
            exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
            exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        }
// optional features
compile ("org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0-rc1")
        {
            exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
            exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        }


compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'





testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0"
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
}
```

and

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
  }
```

Comment: help! :). I think i will probably just delete the project and start again. Its kind of the last thing i can think of tbh!?

Comment: still haven't figured this out. think its a potential IDE quirk.

Answer (score 0):

Could you see if you have in this way your settings:

1.In build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

2.In gradle-wrapper.properties make sure to use gradle 2.2.1

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

3.Sync project with gradle files by pressing the button to the left of the avd button

[image]

4.Try to build project again. If still having issues possibly try **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Doing this way worked for me

I follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19496969/2091181

Comment: iam using mavenCentral()

Comment: it seems to build then i get more errors to do with Dagger. damn

Comment: to do with the "Dagger" annotation when creating a component. iam guessing thats why it wont make the .apk.

Comment: Did you add  repositories {mavenCentral()} to your build.gradle file?

Comment: yes changed it from jcenter()  to mavenCentral(). also added 
    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'  and compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28' to my app build.gradle. the issue seems to be with "Daggermycomponent" and the import javax.annotation.Generated

Comment: i dont have all these exact dependencies  but i do have the plugin applied apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' and the dependencies   compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

Comment: i also read somewhere that 'apt' wasn't needed with dagger 2.0 but iam not 100%. been reading way too many stackoverflow questions

Comment: ive added my gradle.build files above.