# "Failed to complete gradle execution" when Run application, after further sync getting error local path doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am stucked with very strange problem in android studio.

I have to different modules in my android application, and using the second module class in my first module.

When I build my gradle with synchronization, it build successfully.

but, when I run I got error

> "Failed to complete gradle execution"

after that I again synchronize my gradle then my application is able to run but I got another error

> "local path doesn't exist"

in RUN window and

> "Execution failed for task ':app:preDexBetaDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1 "

in GRADLE window.

I can't understand what happening here.

my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 215
    versionName '1.0.42'

}

compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

}

lintOptions {

    // problems with generated "applicationId" string resource
    disable 'MissingTranslation'

}

productFlavors {

  dev {

        applicationId "com.xabber.androiddev"
        resValue 'string', 'application_package', applicationId

    }

    beta {

        applicationId "com.xabber.android.beta"
        resValue 'string', 'application_package', applicationId

    }

    prod {

        applicationId "com.xabber.android"
        resValue 'string', 'application_package', applicationId

    }

    vip {

        applicationId "com.xabber.androidvip"
        resValue 'string', 'application_package', applicationId

    }
}
}

repositories {

mavenCentral()

}

ext {

smackVersion = '4.1.3'

}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0'
compile 'dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.7'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.1.0'
compile 'com.jcraft:jzlib:1.0.7'
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:$smackVersion"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:$smackVersion"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:$smackVersion"
compile project('otr4j')
compile project('MemorizingTrustManager')
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'

}
```

Comment: add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in gradle

Comment: still getting same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist try this one .

Comment: I tried all links of stackoverflow related to this topic, but not working.

Comment: hey...i am also trying to build xabber client..and getting the same error..did u resolve this error? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

same problem came to me also..

I removed  `compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'` this line , and problem solved.

and try to update:

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
```

Comment: Sorry, it also not helping.

Comment: with "Execution failed for task ':app:preDexBetaDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 " I am getting this error: AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}

Comment: hey man...did u resolve this issue...i m also getting same error. i m trying to build xabber android client