# Android studio 1.0 Local path doesn't exist

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I just updated from android studio 0.9 to 1.0 and now when i try to run my app everything goes well up to the point where it asks "choose device", then i select my note 4 and then issues error "Local path doesn't exist."

I am using 64bit windows

Also clicked on "Sync Project with Gradle files". The problem is still there!

App:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-sm_...
Uploading file
    local path: C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\app.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.MyApp
Local path doesn't exist.
```

Error Log:

```
11:32:40 AM Gradle build finished in 5 sec
11:32:43 AM Unexpected Error
            Local path doesn't exist.
Local path doesn't exist.
The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.
            Sync Project with Gradle files
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with APK_PATH, which for some reason can't be found..

You may try following the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994596/android-studio-is-not-loading-on-the-device-local-path-doesnt-exist) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist).

Also, you may try updating your Gradle plugin to the latest version and rebuilding the project.

Comment: +1 for update gradle. I think the version of gradle needs to be compatible with the build tools version etc etc. twist some knobs pull some levers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the file from an Unix system? The path slashes are different in each one. Try correcting the paths to match your current system.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same error.

1. And I cleaned and rebuild the project and

> Project -> Clean Project/ Build Project

2. Synced the project using Gradle

> Click on "Sync Project with Gradle files" in Event Log

And you should be good. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Run/Debug Configurations you have.

Click on the icon that has the Android robot written app then click on Android Configuration. When you click on "app", you will see to the right, at the bottom there is "Before launch..." Make sure in the input box below that it says "Gradle-aware Make". If it doesn't, click on whatever it says and click the pencil icon just above it (it is for editing). In the dialog box that pops up, remove whatever command is there (sometimes it is to unistallAll before reinstalling the new updated apk) and click "Okay". When you come back, you will see the input box now has "Gradle-aware Make" which means when you build your app, it will just install it on top of what is there.

I had this issue because I was unistalling everything before installing the new apk but I once cut the process in the middle of this process after it unistalled but not reinstalled. This meant the next time I ran the app, it wanted to unistall but could not find the apk as it has been deleted before. Changed back the configuration like above and it worked.